# Como compilar e executar programa em C utilizando o Sublime Text no Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, sublime-text, sublime-text-2

É possível configurar o Sublime Text 2 para que ele compile um código em C e depois execute e mostre o resultado no terminal?

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 1):

Sim, é possível configurar o sistema de *build* dele. Imagino que você já conheça a [documentação](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/build_systems.html). O que provavelmente te falta é como criar um arquivo de configuração no Linux. Provavelmente isto funciona:

```
{
    "linux":
    {
        "cmd": ["cc","-std=c99" ,"$file_name","-o", "${file_base_name}", "-lm", "-Wall", ";", "./${file_base_name}"]
    },
    "selector" : "source.c",
    "shell": true,
    "working_dir" : "$file_path",
}
```

Retirado dessa [resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13671068/221800).

Isto pode ter que ser adaptado dependendo de como está sua instalação.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Eu comecei a usar o Sublime há pouco tempo e já havia visto essa build, só que ela não funcionou aqui. Apresenta esse erro: "Error trying to parse build system: Trailing comma before closing bracket in ~/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/User/test.sublime-build:9:1"

Comment: Eu também nunca usei mas tem várias pessoas usando esta configuração.

Comment: Consegui corrigir o erro que estava dando mas o resultado foi mostrado dentro do próprio Sublime, eu queria que imprimisse no terminal. Será que não tem como?

Comment: Até onde eu vi não tem como, mas não posso garantir. Na própria resposta que eu *linkei* fala sobre isto.

Comment: Pelo menos em Python é possível, segundo esse site: http://pythoneiro.blogspot.com.br/2014/10/sublime-text-3-executando-script-no.html